# Paypal Errors control

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm integrating `paypal Checkout` with `server-side SDK`. I'm trying to figure out how to handle errors and I can't get the answers to these questions:

`1)`In CreateOrder , after receiving the response from Paypal, I save the data in DB. If saving data gives an exception, the data will be inconsistent between what is in `Paypal` and what I have in DB. Is there any way to delete the created order, in Paypal? (This is because I'd thinking try to make the payment again, but as the `order_id` generated has associated the same `invoice_Id`, it will cause problems, right?). I've notice there is no "Delete" in `Orders API`, so how can I delete it?

`2)`If saving data in my DB gives an exception after `CaptureOrder`, I will have to ask for a `refund` for that `capture_id` to have the same information in DB and `Paypal`. After the `refund` is done, I'd like to make the payment again, can I used the same `invoice_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orders that have not been captured/completed cannot be deleted. Simply forget about them and do not capture them. The invoice_id can be used in other orders, since it only matters for completed orders.

Re-using an invoice ID after refunding an order likely will not work, since it is meant to prevent such duplicate payments. But that something you would need to test yourself.